# Indexing column of excel from outside the function in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, function, character

I want to call my function by passing the inputs that are the Excel's column names.
For example consider the following command `xlsread(data,'name:name');`to be inside the function and I want to call the function by passing the name like the following:

```
myfun(A);
```

But this gives me error message since A is not defined. I have tried doing the following

```
myfun('A')
```

This also give me error message. Can anyone tell me how to pass the character to xlsread inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xlsread(data, [name, ‘:’, name])`, where `data` is the file name and `name` is the character string that you pass.